# How to fix incorrect radio button size in Dolphin class browser?

Tags: smalltalk, dolphin-smalltalk

In my Dophin Class browser I see that the Instance/Class radio buttons have their text splitted in two rows, as you can see in the attached image.
What can I do about it ?
Maurizio.

[image: Incorrect radio buttons]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the field wider. One thing to try is to make the entire window wider. Depending on the layout, that may increase the width of this element. Next, you can try changing the default font for the code browser. With a smaller font the same text might be enough to get the text on one line. Finally, you can find the class for the browser and edit the width of the GUI.

Comment: Changing the default font solved the problem. Thanks. Maurizio

Comment: @MaurizioFerreira please don't forget to mark the answer as correct. James has helped you a couple of times and he has a small reputation here at SO (although we know him very well in Smalltalk communities)

Comment: Done.
(I didn't know about this feature).